# How can I get the position from FlowDocumentScrollViewer?

Tags: wpf, flowdocument, flowdocumentscrollviewer

I'm trying to get the position from FlowDocumentScrollViewer.
And save it to db.

After that, close and re-open the program.
At that time, the scroll should be set to what I saved position.

Simply, I hope to save that I watched position. and later, when I open it, I want to see the position which I watched last time.

Now, I'm watching this class, but I couldn't find some method or variables about this feature.
FlowDocumentPageViewer has GoToPage(), so I hope to get this kind of method from FlowDocumentScrollViewer.

How can I create thesas feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/561319/5018591) you need to get the scollviewer property of your FlowDocumentScrollViewer. than you can get scrollbar position with myScrollViewer.VerticalOffset and set it with myScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(double value)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already saw this page, but I thought I cannot effective to my situation. I will try it again. Thanks!